# firebase functions emulators not starting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

as you all aware about firebase CLI's new feature which is local emulators explained here(https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/05/local-firebase-emulator-ui.html?m=1)

so I have updated my CLI and when I run firebase emulators:start I get this error in my functions code

```
kishan@kishans-Air functions % firebase emulators:start
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions
⚠  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "10"
⚠  hosting: The hosting emulator is configured but there is no hosting configuration. Have you run firebase init hosting?
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "/Users/kishan/Desktop/dilip/googlecloudfunctions/functions" for Cloud Functions...
⚠  TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:311:83)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kishan/Desktop/dilip/googlecloudfunctions/functions/lib/index.js:7:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:661:33
⚠  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
   - It appears your code is written in Typescript, which must be compiled before emulation.
```

can anyone help what I need to do here ??

Answer (score 1):

The error message is suggesting to you:

> It appears your code is written in Typescript, which must be compiled before emulation.

You have to build the code first with `npm run build`.  The emulator will not do that for you.

Comment: That is not the issue here, I'm having the same problem and I have compiled typescript. There is something wrong in functionsEmulatorRuntime - It is trying to console log an empty object, which causes this error. Seems to be something with functions.config().firebase not working in the emulators.

Comment: functions.config().firebase is deprecated.  If you don't have specific config for the Firebase Admin SDK, then just call initalizeApp  with no args to take the defaults for your project.

Answer (score 1):

I found that instead of calling:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
```

I had to instead call:

```
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});
```

This resolved the issue.